# Nginxのアクセスログ、エラーログの出力について

Tags: nginx

私はraspberry piにNginxを入れて使っているんですが、ログが出力されなくて困っています。
パスはデフォルトの /var/log/nginx/ なんですが、元からそこになくて私が新しくそのディレクトリに作りました。
nginxのconfファイルにもログのパスは上記のものを設定していて再起動しても症状は改善されません。
この場合にどこに原因があると考えられますか？

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/` のパーミッションとオーナー、グループ、また nginx の実行ユーザはなんですか？

Comment: あっ！
そこを確認んしたらパーミッションが読み込みだけでした。ありがとうございます！